# What encryption to choose for secure directory on USB Storage?

Tags: pi-3, filesystem, security

I need to choose encryption tool to secure my USB stored files, and I'm stuck with tools like VeraCrypt, ecryptfs or dm-crypt. The task is to encrypt folder or virtual disk that could be mounted as decrypted volume and also should be able to recover if i meesed something with Pi system or SDCard.

Which one should I chose for best performance and security on Pi3?

Comment: Have you tried googling your problem? This site isn’t suppose to recommend you a specific program

Comment: Yes, sure. After that, I end with this 3 tools, but i can't find any comparison about strength and performance on Pi3. I would to know which one is strongest and fastest on Pi3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some simple tests to compare performance of `dm-crypt`, `ecryptfs` and `encfs`. Test was very simple, just copy 2GB of random data to each encrypted volume. Volume are stored on the same USB Disk (Magnetic) connected to RPi3.

Results:

```
         | size    | write     | read
---------+---------+-----------+-----------
raw      | 2.0 GiB | 32.7 MB/s | 30.9 MB/s
dm-crypt | 2.0 GiB | 28.3 MB/s | 30.8 MB/s
ecryptfs | 2.0 GiB | 12.3 MB/s | 31.5 MB/s
encfs    | 2.0 GiB |  7.7 MB/s | 13.5 MB/s
```

I connot install `VeraCrypt` or other `TrueCrypt` fork to make test. I had problems with installing this tools, and I give up finally.